# Google sheet script to add a row above a specific cell once that has been filtered out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to build a spreadsheet where a button, once it's been clicked, it would build a new row above a specific cell containing a fixed value/sting.

Practical example would be a sheet containing cells with different values and the script should run through all the cells, find a cell with a specific string and add an empty row above that.

I've been looking around for a similar script to tweak and adapt to my situation but all of my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

This is what I've got:

```
function AddRowAbove() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // get the active sheet

  var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange(); //get all the data in the spreadsheet (is that the right way to do this??

  // for every data within the range of data variable
  for (var i = 0; i< rangeData.length ; i++){ 
    if(rangeData[i] == "TOT")            // Check to see if cell has "TOT" as value

    {
      ss.insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getCell(rawData[i]), 1); // is that the right function to call???
    }
  }
```

Though logically this seems to be correct, I'm not used to script with this programming language so it's hard for me to find where the problem is.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also, can anyone point me out to any resource I can study to get the basic of this scripting language??

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help answer your question? [How to check if the value exist in google spreadsheet or not using apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695894/how-to-check-if-the-value-exist-in-google-spreadsheet-or-not-using-apps-script)

Comment: Are the cell values that you need to check in one particular column or distributed in the sheet anywhere? It it is the latter then what is the intended outcome if say "TOT" is present in B1 and B3? Do you add two rows above or just one?

Comment: Hey Broly, thanks for replying. 
I'm making sure that whatever I look for in that particular cell value is unique so there would not be the problem of having two result.
The value i need to check is in one particular column if that makes things easier to script though it would be better to check in the entire sheet so i could change the layout if needed (does that make sense at all??)
Thanks a lot for helping...I'm still trying tweaking my code but no good results yet :(

Comment: My main problem is being debugging the script to see if i'm getting the right results. Usually that is easily done with a Print command to check what's stored in a variable but here since it's a script working on a spreadsheet I don't know if that is possible.
I'm trying to get the cell i'm looking for and then Highlight it (or activate it) in the spreadsheet so at least I know the filter is working but I can't get that either!
You can guess my knowledge on this is pretty low, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You will have to use . getValue method on rangeData and then compare to "TOT". To debug you can use Logger.log(rangeData[I].getValue()) to see what cell value was picked.